# Android source referencing missing classes

Tags: android, android-source

I cloned some of the trees from the Android Open Source Project to take a look at the code, but I can't build them because they reference classes which don't seem to exist.

For instance, the music application [here](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Music.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/music/AlbumBrowserActivity.java;h=ba3e2127606f310f61b1f32fe2d01656cd81a57e;hb=master) references `android.media.MediaFile` which according to the [package summary](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/package-summary.html) does not exist, as well as things like `ArrayListCursor` which has an old [javadoc](http://www.androidjavadoc.com/m5-rc15/android/database/ArrayListCursor.html) around but is [absent in current documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/AbstractCursor.html).

So is the open source project disjoint from the released SDK? Also, is there a way to build these open source packages with the current SDK?

Thanks,

-JQP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So is the open source project disjoint
>   from the released SDK?

The stock Android applications have nothing whatsoever to do with the SDK. Most were written before the SDK existed.

So, for example, there is an [`android.media.MediaFile`](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/media/java/android/media/MediaFile.java&q=package:android%20MediaFile&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc) class, and an [`ArrayListCursor`](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/com/android/internal/database/ArrayListCursor.java&q=package:android%20ArrayListCursor&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc) class. They are not part of the SDK, but you can find the source for them quickly using [Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=en) and the `package:android` qualifier.

> Also, is there a way to build these
>   open source packages with the current
>   SDK?

If by "open source packages" you mean applications, then generally no, they cannot be built using the SDK. Someday, perhaps they can be, but not without substantial work in some cases.