# Is it Possible to filter with duration of .mp3 file While Using Intent.createchooser?

Tags: android

In my android application I am using the below code to list out the mp3 files for select and upload.
 I want to know  is it possible to filter the files with their duration along with their type.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("audio/*");              
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
try {
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select your Audio"), Global.FILE_FROM_SD);
} 
catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog
    Toast.makeText(WizardStep1.this,
            "Please install a File Manager.",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so, or at least not the way how you started.

I believe once you created the intent chooser and opened another file manager, then you cannot control what data to display you that particular file manager, like filtered by a particular criteria.

The solution I see here, is to create a method that [returns all audio files from sdcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994625/display-all-music-on-sd-card) into an array, then use a filter to determine the extension of your files (.mp3) in conjuction with a method that [gets the duration of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802398/determining-the-duration-and-format-of-an-audio-file).
Add the the filtered content to a new array, and then do what you want with your filtered files, for example display in a `ListView` and let the user select the ones which he want to upload.

A pseudocode will look like this:

```
ArrayList<String> filteredFiles = new ArrayList<String>();

String[] audioFiles = getAllAudioFiles();
for (String file : audioFiles) {
    if (file.endsWith(".mp3") && getDuration(file) >= DURATION_CONSTANT) {
        filteredFiles.add(file);
    }
}
```

Then display the content of `filteredFiles` in a `ListView` and provide the appropriate logic for selecting/uploading the file.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, this is not possible. The intent receiver can handle a MIME type such as `audio/*`

Purpose of MIME types are to express the type of media you expect/request/accept. It doesn't support any attributes (AFAIK)

Even if it did, I don't think more than a handful of Android applications would bother to support it to fulfill your scenario.

You will have a better luck passing application specific 'extra' data using [Intent.putExtra (String name, Bundle value)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29) if you can find an app that supports accepting such extra data. The popular [ES File Explorer](http://www.estrongs.com/en/support/developers.html) app doesn't seems to support it, so I don't think this will work for the majority of your users.

Comment: Thank you Madushan, I am also thinking in this way need to confirm.once again thank you for your valuable answer